# How to improve performance of neo4j base database

Tags: performance, database-design, graph, neo4j

We have created the neo4j database using below query. Our csv files contains 50k rows.

```
// Query1
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:PR) ASSERT p.prId IS UNIQUE;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///2015_PRData.csv' AS line WITH line,
SPLIT(SPLIT(line.`Open Date`, ' ')[0], '/') AS opnDateList,
SPLIT(SPLIT(line.`Closed Date`, ' ')[0], '/') AS clsDateList
MERGE (prNode:PR{prId:TOINT(line.prId)})
MERGE (app:Application{appName:line.Application})
MERGE (func:Function{funName:line.Function})
MERGE (subfunc:SubFunction{subFunName:line.Subfunction})
MERGE (cat:Category{catName:line.Category})
MERGE (rel:Release{relName:line.Release})
MERGE (custNode:Customer{customerName:line.`Server Name`})
MERGE (prOpenDate:PROpenDate{openDate:SPLIT(line.`Open Date`, ' ')[0]})
SET prOpenDate.day = TOINT(opnDateList[1]),prOpenDate.month = TOINT(opnDateList[0]),prOpenDate.year = opnDateList[2]
MERGE (prClosedDate:PRClosedDate{closedDate:SPLIT(line.`Closed Date`, ' ')[0]})
SET prClosedDate.day = TOINT(clsDateList[1]),prClosedDate.month = TOINT(clsDateList[0]),prClosedDate.year = clsDateList[2]
MERGE (app)-[:PART_OF_APPLN]->(func)
MERGE (func)-[:PART_OF_FUNCTION]->(subfunc)
MERGE (subfunc)-[:PART_OF_SUBFUNCTION]->(cat)
MERGE (prNode)-[:CATEGORY]->(cat)
MERGE (prNode)-[:REPORTED_BY]->(custNode)
MERGE (prNode)-[:OPEN_ON]->(prOpenDate)
MERGE (prNode)-[:CLOSED_ON]->(prClosedDate)
MERGE (prNode)-[:REPORTED_IN]->(rel)

Query 2:
//change year for open date nodes
MERGE (q:PROpenDate) SET q.year=SPLIT(q.year,' ')[0] return q;

Query 3:
//change year for closed date nodes
MERGE (q:PRClosedDate) SET q.year=SPLIT(q.year,' ')[0] return q;

Query 4:
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///2015_PR_WithCP.csv' AS line WITH line
MERGE (cpNode:CP{cpId:line.cpId})
MERGE (prnode:PR{prId:TOINT(SPLIT(line.prRefId, 'PR')[1])})
CREATE (prnode)-[:FIXED_BY]->(cpNode)

Query 5:
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///2015_CPWithFilename.csv' AS line WITH line
MERGE (cpNode:CP{cpId:line.cpId})
MERGE (cpFile:FILE{fileName:line.fileName})
CREATE (cpNode)-[:CONTAINS]->(cpFile)

Query 6:   
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///2015_CPcomments.csv' AS line
MERGE (cpNode:CP{cpId:line.cpId})
MERGE (fileNode:FILE{fileName:line.fileName})
MERGE (owner:DougUser{userId:line.cpOwner})
MERGE (reviewer:DougUser{userId:line.cpReviewer})
MERGE (cpNode)-[:SUBMITTED_BY]->(owner)
WITH line WHERE line.reviewComment IS NOT NULL
MERGE (comment:ReviewComment{commentText:line.reviewComment,contextCP:line.cpId})
MERGE (comment)-[:GIVEN_BY]->(reviewer)
MERGE (comment)-[:COMMENT_FOR]->(fileNode)
```

It takes more time to upload the data in neo4j. More than 7 hours for first query.

Also it take more time to fetch the data from server.

```
MATCH (pr:PR)-[:FIXED_BY]-(cp) 
MATCH (cp)-[:CONTAINS]-(file)  
MATCH (pr)-[:CLOSED_ON]-(cls) 
MATCH (pr)-[:REPORTED_BY]-(custs) 
MATCH (pr)-[:CATEGORY]-(cats) 
WHERE  file.fileName STARTS WITH 'xyz'  AND NOT(cls.closedDate = '' )AND 
apoc.date.parse(cls.closedDate,'s', 'MM/dd/yyyy') >= apoc.date.parse('01/01/2014','s', 'MM/dd/yyyy') AND apoc.date.parse(cls.closedDate,'s', 'MM/dd/yyyy') <= apoc.date.parse('06/13/2017','s', 'MM/dd/yyyy') 
RETURN collect(DISTINCT custs.customerName) AS customers, collect(DISTINCT cats.catName) AS categories
```

Above queries takes more than 5 min to fetch the data. Please help me to solve this. Performance is really bad.

Comment: What indexes & constraints do you have ? (`:schema` in the browser)
Have you done some neo4j configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is likely a lack of indexes/constraints when you perform each MERGE. MERGE is like a MATCH or a CREATE, and if you don't have an index on the label/property you're MERGING, then the db must perform a label scan, which means it must check every single node of that label in the database and access all of their properties to find which of those have the property you want, which is expensive. As you add nodes, the label scans (and thus the MERGEs) become slower and slower. Use indexes instead.

In cases where you're using MERGE on a node with multiple properties, if there is a unique property (such as an id property), MERGE only using that property then use ON CREATE SET to set the remaining non-unique properties.

You can check for inefficiencies by using EXPLAIN before your query, which will produce a query plan without executing the query. You want to make sure you see NodeUniqueIndexSeek and NodeIndexSeek. If you see NodeByLabelScan then more than likely you need to optimize your query by adding an index on the relevant label/property.

Some of your queries use MERGE when they should be using MATCH (queries 2 and 3, and likely some nodes within subsequent queries where you know the node already exists). If you're trying to find existing nodes in the database and not trying to add nodes, use MATCH instead.

Query 6 has a flaw in your WITH clause, you also need to include `reviewer` and `fileNode` in the WITH, otherwise these variables will be out of scope and won't be bound to the nodes you previously created earlier in the query.

Query 6 also has an Eager in the query plan (caused by MERGing of both `owner` and `reviewer` nodes), which will prevent periodic commits and cause the query to run inefficiently. To fix this, do an import of all :DougUser nodes first (using a single variable here), and only then execute query 6 (but use MATCH for both `owner` and `reviewer`, since they should exist in the graph).

For query 7, the EXPLAIN plan is showing a NodeByLabelScan, so it will run on all :PR nodes looking for matching patterns. It's probably better to add the :FILE label to the `file` node, which will alter the plan to start with a NodeIndexSeekByRange, so your starting node will be :FILE nodes starting with 'xyz' (via a fast index lookup) and it will find the matching pattern from there.

Comment: I am trying to understand your toughs. But I am pretty new to this neo4j, it will be great if you edit some of my query.

Comment: The first query, the initial load, is all about the constraints/indexes you have set up before the query is even run. Add constraints or indexes on `:Application(appName)`, `:Function(funName)`, `:SubFunction(subFunName)`, `:Category(catName)`, `:Release(relName)`, `:Customer(customerName)`, `:PROpenDate(openDate)`, and `:PRClosedDate(closedDate)`. You may also want to create indexes/constraints for some of your other nodes added later (like :CP, :FILE, :DougUser, and maybe :ReviewComment). Also, if you add `EXPLAIN` before a query, you'll see the query plan (and the query won't run)

Comment: Without index lookup, you're performing label scans, and these get more and more expensive as the number of nodes in each of these labels grow. If we assume unique nodes are added for each row, you're performing a summation from 1 to 50k lookups, which is 1250025000 label scans, multiplied by the number of node merges (which is 8, since :PR nodes will at least be using a unique index lookup).